# How should I evaluate $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$ with van der waals equation: $P = \frac{nRT}{V-nb}-a(\frac{n}{V})^2$?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy, van-der-waals-behavior

So in my homework I was able to get this-

$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T = T(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_V - P$

but now I'm trying to plug in $P = \frac{nRT}{V-nb}-a(\frac{n}{V})^2$ in the above equation.  I'm struggling here, I got zero for
$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$ but I'm then asked to evaluate $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T$ in an integral from infinity to $V$ with respect to $V$ (i.e. $dV$).

Comment: Chemistry SE site strongly recommends plain text titles for index/search reasons and due possible displaying issues in question lists.

Comment: For $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T})_V$, just take the derivative of your entire expression for p ($p=\frac{nRT}{V-nb}-a(\frac{n}{V})^2$ )with respect to T at constant V.  Then multiply by T, and subtract  the expression for p....exactly as your equation says.  *If you're getting zero, I suspect what you are doing is subtracting only the first of the two terms in the expression for p, rather than the whole thing.*  General suggestion: When you can't get the right answer, instead of trying to find the error in what you've done, start over from scratch; that way you're less likely to repeat it.